# Using AddRange and Cast to merge data of different datatype together in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my code below I am having issue on this line:

```
transactiongetalert = serv.GetAlertThresholdCall(AcctNo));
```

The error: cannot implicitly convert type.... from... to

```
Models.xmlGetResponse c = new Models.xmlGetResponse();
var serv = new SelfServiceServices();
string _xmlString = serv.GetLoggedUserAccessAccount(loggedusersession.LoggedSessionId);
XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();

x.LoadXml(_xmlString);

string AcctNo;
var accts = x.GetElementsByTagName("AccountNumber");
var GlobalListOfTranAlerts = new List<AlertResponse>();
List<AlertResponse> transactiongetalert = new List<AlertResponse>();

foreach (XmlElement a in accts)
{
  AcctNo = a.InnerText; 
  transactiongetalert = serv.GetAlertThresholdCall(AcctNo));
  GlobalListOfTranAlerts.AddRange(transactiongetalert);
}

return View(GlobalListOfTranAlerts);
```

Please who can help me out; Thanks in advance.

Declaration: AlertResponse SelfServiceServices.GetAlertThresholdCall(string AccountNo) where  SelfServiceServices is a public class

Detailed Error: Cannot implicitly convert type ‘Namespace.WebServiceConnect.AlertResponse’ to ‘System.Collections.Generic.List’

Comment: You'd at least need to show what `GetAlertThresholdCall` returns. My guess is it's not `List<AlertResponse>`.

Comment: GetAlertThresholdCall returns AlertResponse                                        Class (   string a, string b, string c, string d, string e, string f )

Comment: Then you are trying to assign an `AlertResponse` instance to a `List<AlertResponse>` variable.  The two are not the same.  Try `transactionGetAlert.Add(serv.GetAlertThresholdCall(AcctNo));`

Comment: @Corey thanks but still getting error: cannot implicitly convert from type

Comment: Can you copy the exact error message text and post it in your question, with the declaration line of your `GetAlertThresholdCall` method as well.

Comment: @Corey i added the exact error and method declaration... thanks alot